# How do I return a variable from a tkinter Entry field to use in another function by pressing a button?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, return

This is a simplified version of my program, where I have created a User Interface with an entry field and a button. Basically, the program should store the user's input as a variable to be able to use it in another function that returns my results. The problem: I cannot find a way to return the variable in order to use it further when pressing the Submit button. How can I do this? Here is the code:

```
win = tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(win, width = 800, height = 700,  relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()

B = tk.StringVar()
C = ""

def run(C):
    D = C + 's'
    return D

def button():
    global C
    A = B.get()
    C = A
    # tried return A but didn't work


e = tk.Entry(win, textvariable = B)
canvas1.create_window(310, 65, window=e)

Submit = tk.Button(win, text = "Submit", command = button)
#tried with lambda function but didn't work
canvas1.create_window(700, 250, window=Submit)

print(run(C))

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: So after user press button, result of `run(C)` should appear in terminal with C being given in entry by user?

Comment: actually I need to use the return value of run(C) afterwards, print(run(C)) was just a simplification

Comment: why don't you just call `B.get()` or `e.get()`  inside of `run`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply your code like this:

```
Submit = tk.Button(win, text = "Submit", command = lambda:button(e.get()))
```

Definition for the button will be:

```
def button(user_input):
    print(user_input)
```

Here, `e.get()` will fetch the data from Entry field and will pass to the function as argument.

Comment: is there any way i can return user_input from the button function and use it afterwards in the run function rather than print it there? i really need to use that variable afterwards outside my button function in the main function